# how to check for condition for multiple inputs before taking in single line?

Tags: python-3.x

```python
def round_1():
    x1, y1, z1 = input("enter the oxygen levels of three (seperate with 
space)person in R1:").split()
    if x1 and y1 and z1 in range(1,101):
       print(x1)
    else:
        print("u enter Wrong")
```

The input is like `50 60 70`. It must be range 1-100; otherwise it has to show "wrong input".

Comment: improve the format of your question

Answer (score 0):

Check this out (This works for more than 3 inputs) -

```
def round_1():
    flag = True  # intialising flag
    lst = input("enter the oxygen levels of three(seperate with"
                "space)person in R1: ").split(" ")

    for i in lst:
        i = int(i)  # since all the elements in the list are of str type
        if i in range(101):
            continue
        else:
            flag = False

    if flag == True:
        print(lst[0])
    else:
        print("wrong input")


round_1()
```

As `x1` , `y1` and `z1` are all strings you need to first typecast them into `int`.

Here's your corrected code -

```
def round_1():
    x1, y1, z1 = input("enter the oxygen levels of three (seperate with "
"space)person in R1:").split()
    if int(x1) and int(y1) and int(z1) in range(1,101):
        print(x1)
    else:
        print("u enter Wrong") 

round_1()
```